# ubuntu 16.04 mplayer fullscreen issue

Tags: ffmpeg, fullscreen, mplayer, vdpau

MPlayer refuses to go fullscreen when I start it with `-noborder` option. Without this option it works fine.

I tried following command but it does not work.

```
mplayer -vo vpdau -zoom -fs -noborder video.mp4

MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing video.mp4.
Cache fill:  0.00% (0 bytes)   

libavformat version 56.40.101 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7ff4916b6e00]Protocol name not provided, cannot determine if input is local or a network protocol, buffers and access patterns cannot be configured optimally without knowing the protocol
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang und
VIDEO:  [H264]  480x268  24bpp  24.000 fps  199.9 kbps (24.4 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 major_brand: mp42
 minor_version: 1
 compatible_brands: isommp423gp5
 creation_time: 2016-04-11 05:19:05
Load subtitles in ./
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Opening video filter: [scale w=700 h=-3]
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 96.0 kbit/3.40% (ratio: 11999->352800)
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
AO: [alsa] 44100Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
[Mixer] No hardware mixing, inserting volume filter.
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 1.78:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
[swscaler @ 0x7ff49195afa0]bicubic scaler, from yuv420p to yuv420p using MMXEXT
VO: [vdpau] 700x390 => 700x393 Planar YV12  [fs] [zoom]
```

I also tried with gl, x11, xv. None of these work with `-noborder` and all of these work without it.

**Update:**

```
mplayer -vo help
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
Available video output drivers:
```

nothing is listed.

Comment: Commandline works fine here. You seem to have a VA-API enabled MPlayer, could you add the results of `mplayer -vo help` to your question?